# Determine the r/w mode of named pipe that the client is using

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

Windows named pipes. The pipe is created in duplex mode. Once the connection is accepted by the server by calling `ConnectNamedPipe`, how can the server determine if the client opened the pipe for reading, writing, or both? "Impossible" is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### AFAIK, what you are asking for is impossible.

A pipe `HANDLE` can be queried for quite a few things, including:

- the pipe's buffer sizes
- whether the pipe is operating in byte mode or message mode
- whether or not the pipe is operating in non-blocking mode
- checking if a pipe handle is the client end or server end of the pipe

But, I don't see any way to query a pipe `HANDLE` whether the *peer* on the other end of the pipe had opened the pipe for reading and/or writing on their end.

So, all your server can really do is just try to read/peek from the pipe, and/or write to the pipe, and check whether that operation fails.